# Client-side validation module, fields required only if certain values in other fields are set

Tags: webforms, forms

We've built a form using WebForms and are using the [Client Side Validation](http://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation) module for AJAX/jQuery validation.

One field on the form needs to only be mandatory if a certain country is selected in the drop down.

We've got as far as being able to customise the styling (the jQuery side of things) to hide/show the required field notice, but we can't seem to dynamically alter the validation rules that the module is working to.

How can we achieve this?

Comment: You cant do it with Client Side Validation module. It is not designed to that scenario. You need to do it with custom jQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always create a custom rule for [Client Side Validation](http://drupal.org/project/clientside_validation), check [clientside_validation.api.js](http://drupalcode.org/project/clientside_validation.git/blob/refs/heads/7.x-1.x:/clientside_validation.api.js) for instructions, but you'll need some coding experience, otherwise feel free to open a [feature request](http://drupal.org/node/add/project-issue/clientside_validation) and we'll see what we can do.